# How to change the replicated backup retention period of an RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an RDS instance which resides in us-east-1. I have enabled automated backups and set the retention period to 3 days. I have also recently enabled backup replication in us-west-2.

The retention period for the replicated back ups is 7 days and I can not find any way to change this setting.

I've looked all over the AWS Console for a setting to change. I've also looked through the CLI reference (specifically at the command modify-db-instance) without finding any way to edit this setting.